# What to expect if Azure App Service CPU maxes out momentarily?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-app-service-plans

I currently have an Azure App Service API that usually runs extremely low average and max CPU (<10% utilization). Every now and again, the CPU will spike due to a temporary spike in client requests. These spikes seemingly only last for a split second, but I’m wondering if this is cause for concern. What is the result of an Azure App Service CPU maxing out temporarily (either for a split second or for several seconds). Will this cause the app to crash, or will it just buffer requests until intensive tasks complete? It is worth noting that despite the spike in CPU, memory utilization remains low. Thanks in advance for input.

It looks like the CPU load is caused entirely from a large number of intensive requests all coming in at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

When the CPU utilization of your Azure App Service API spikes temporarily, it could cause the app to slow down or become unresponsive, depending on the level and duration of the spike.

The system will try to buffer requests during this time, but if the spike is too high, some requests may be dropped or time out. This can result in a poor user experience or errors, especially if the spike is sustained for an extended period of time.

To mitigate this issue, you can take a few steps.

1. You can optimize the code of your API to reduce the CPU utilization of each request. This could involve reducing the number of operations performed for each request, using caching or other performance-enhancing techniques, or optimizing the algorithm used for processing requests.
2. You can also consider scaling up the resources of your App Service, such as increasing the number of CPU cores or adding more memory, to handle the increased load during spikes. Another option is to use horizontal scaling by adding more instances of your API to distribute the load across multiple servers, which can help reduce the impact of spikes.

And you can monitor your App Service to detect and respond to spikes in CPU utilization in real-time.
For example, you can use Azure Monitor to set up alerts that trigger when CPU utilization exceeds a certain threshold, and automatically scale your App Service in response.
By checking the Azure monitor logs and Web App Diagnostics, can find the reasons behind CPU Utilization.

1. Diagnose and solve problems:

[image]

2. CPU Usage:

[image]

3. CPU Drill Down:

[image]

References taken from

[Application monitoring for Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps)

[CPU Diagnostics, Identify and Diagnose High CPU issues](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/10/05/Diagnose-App-with-High-CPU.html)